# Ruby on Rails: Displaying model attribute on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So I have a user model and a store model created. I am having a problem displaying the name of a store that has already been created in my database. It's a very stupid problem, with a very easy solution, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. So here is my user controller where I find the store I want to display:

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @store = Store.find(1)
end
```

And here is the view:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.username) %>
 <div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
   <section class="user_info">
     <h1>
       <%= gravatar_for @user %>
       <%= @user.username %>
     </h1>
   </section>
 </aside>
</div>

<li><% @store.name %></li>
```

So the name of the user shows up, no issues there, but for some reason, the name of the store is not showing up. I know as a fact that there is a store with an id: 1 in the database. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To output content with ERB, you need to add an `=` to the ERB block:

```
<%= @store.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this,

```
<li><%= @store.name %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets see which `ERB` tag does what:

```
<%= %> # Prints the attribute value.
Welcome to <%= @store.name %>!


<% %> # Executes the code.
<ul>
  <% @stores.each do |store| %>
  <li><%= store.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>


<%# %> # Comments out the code.
<%# This is just a comment... %>
```

Rails extends ERB, so you can use this shortcut to suppress new line:

```
<% -%> # Avoids line break after expression.
<ul>
  <% @stores.each do |store| -%>
  <li><%= store.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

For further study, see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).